# How can I remove all the punctuations from a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, punctuation

for removing  all punctuations from a string, x.
i want to use re.findall(), but i've been struggling to know what to write **in** it..
i know that i can get **all** the punctuations by writing:

```
import string
y = string.punctuation
```

but if i write:

```
re.findall(y,x)
```

it says:

```
 raise error("multiple repeat")
 sre_constants.error: multiple repeat
```

can someone explain what exactly we should write in `re.findall` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may not even need RegEx for this. You can simply use `translate`, like this

```
import string
print data.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

Comment: FYI, In Python 3, [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) does not take `delete` parameter. should be converted to `bytes`: `data.encode().translate(None, string.punctuation.encode()).decode()`

Comment: what is data? it's my original string?

Comment: Yes, `data` in this example should be a name referring to your original string. `translate` is a method available on any string object. Its behavior is described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate - in this instance, it is accepting a `None` argument for character replacements and a constant defining characters to delete.

Comment: @falsetru: for this operation to handle non-ASCII text, you would in any case have to account for the fact that `string.punctuation` doesn't contain all the punctuation characters, only the ASCII ones. So you'd want something like `''.join(ch for ch in data if unicodedata.category(ch)[0] != 'P')`. Just encoding everything will fail to remove non-ASCII punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

Several characters in `string.punctuation` have special meaning in regular expression. They should be escaped.

```
>>> import re
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> import re
>>> re.escape(string.punctuation)
'\\!\\"\\#\\$\\%\\&\\\'\\(\\)\\*\\+\\,\\-\\.\\/\\:\\;\\<\\=\\>\\?\\@\\[\\\\\\]\\^\\_\\`\\{\\|\\}\\~'
```

And if you want to match any one of them, use character class (`[...]`)

```
>>> '[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation))
'[\\!\\"\\#\\$\\%\\&\\\'\\(\\)\\*\\+\\,\\-\\.\\/\\:\\;\\<\\=\\>\\?\\@\\[\\\\\\]\\^\\_\\`\\{\\|\\}\\~]'
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation))
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', 'Hell,o World.')
'Hello World'
```